# Почему plt.imshow(x) не работает в pycharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib

В jupyter этот код работает без проблема, но в  pycharm выводит такую ошибку "Invalid dimensions for image data"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('test.jpg')
imggray = img.convert('LA')
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
plt.imshow(imggray)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените картинку с кодом текстом.

Comment: Выведите `imggray.shape`. Скорее всего у вас файл не открылся.

Comment: Это мой первый вопрос на данном ресурсе, поэтому не сразу разобралась, что нужно предоставлять к вопросу. Текст с кодом добавила, надеюсь вы мне хоть немного подскажите.